# ssh via public keys failing for account on CentOS 6 with user id below 500

Tags: linux, security, ssh, centos, public-key-encryption

I converted a non-login user `jenkins`,  created by the jenkins CI server installation, to allow log in by doing the following:

1. Adding a home dir and shell in the /etc/passwd file for the jenkins user
2. Creating a home directory

I then created a public an private key pair by

1. Added public & private keys in the .ssh directory in the new home space
2. Created and authorized_keys file
3. Set the correct permissions for the .ssh directory and contents.

Now, on the machine, as root I can `su - jenkins` and become the jenkins user.  However, on a remote machine I cannot ssh with public key  to this machine (as the jenkins user with the respective keys).

I created a new user on the machine via useradd, copied the jenkins ssh keys over to this account and was able to log in as this user using the keys.

I'm completely stumped with what is special about the jenkins user that could be blocking ssh public key access.  The only thing that sticks out in my mind is the jenkins user was 
created with User ID of 498.  Is there something blocking 'system' user from allowing ssh?

The end of the ssh command with `-v` enabled for failing login as user jenkins looks like this:

```
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa
 debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
 Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

The successfull login as user foo (with the same keys):

```
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa
 debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
 Authenticated to jenkins.internal.nara.me ([54.83.203.146]:22).
 debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
 debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
 debug1: Entering interactive session.
 debug1: Sending environment.
 debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are likely missing something among this :

- permission on the **home directory** of your jenkins user are not right (like not owned by user, or world or group-writableà
- ssh not allowing key-based authentication for some users
- having an unexpected carrigae-return in the authorized_keys file

to debug this, reload your sshd with

```
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

and look at /var/log/auth.log (or centos equivalent) for information on why this key is not accepted. In verbose mode, sshd always says why ;)

Comment: Thanks, I enabled the LogLevel Verbose.  It just indicates `Failed publickey for jenkins from 50.247.216.241 port 61618 ssh2`, but it's the same keys.  I'll change jenkins home to the working foo user home and change ownership of /home/foo to jenkins to make 100% the keys are identical.

Comment: Ok, something's different with the keys.  Still can't tell what, they look the same, seem to have the same permissions.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction by turning on the SSHD log level higher--I didn't know there was a way to get more info!